# Layout changes when I switch resolution

Tags: html, css, web, resolution

I'm making a website (in Dutch) and I work on a laptop with a external screen. The external screen has another resolution then my laptop screen so the site comes out distorted when viewed on the other screen. How do I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>  <style type="text/css">

body {
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
nav {
/* Dit is voor de menubalk bovenin. */
position: relative;
background-color: black;
width: 100%;
height: 110px;
top: -16px;
left: -7.8px;
padding: 8px;
}
.menutekst1 {
position: relative;
width: 150px;
display: inline;
border-color: white;
color: white;
list-style-type: none;
float: right;
font-size: 39px;
top: 10px;
right: 40px;
font-family: verdana;

}
.menutekst2 {
position: relative;
display: inline;
border-color: white;
color: white;
list-style-type: none;
float: right;
font-size: 39px;
top: 10px;
right: 25px;
font-family: verdana;
}
.menutekst3 {
position: relative;
display: inline;
border-color: white;
color: white;
list-style-type: none;
float: right;
font-size: 39px;
top: 10px;
right: 50px;
font-family: verdana;
}
.menutekst4 {
position: relative;
display: inline;
border-color: white;
color: white;
list-style-type: none;
float: right;
font-size: 39px;
top: 10px;
font-family: verdana;
}
#logo {
/* Dit is voor het logo rechts bovenin. */
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 0px;
width: 300px;
}
#facebook {
/* Dit is voor het Facebook logo rechts bovenin. */
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 320px;
width: 70px;
}
#hometekst {
/* Dit is voor de tekst op de home pagina. */
position: relative;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: Verdana;
}
#home1 {
position: relative;
display: inline;
width: 250px;
height: 161px;
float: left;
left: 0px;
/* left: 40px; */
}
#home2 {
position: relative;
display: inline;
width: 320px;
height: 161px;
float: right;
left: px;
right: 250px; */
}
#home3 {
position: relative;
display: inline;
width: 250px;
height: 161px;
float: right;
/* right: 50px; */
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <img id="logo" src="Foto/logoalgemeen.png" />

        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Ve-screen-Ve-woning-en-scheepsstoffering/369675879764436?fref=ts" target="_blank" title="Facebook"><img id="facebook" src="Foto/facebookalgemeen.png" /></a>

        <div class="menutekst4"><li>Contact </li></div>
        <div class="menutekst2"><li>Wat doen wij  </li></div>
        <div class="menutekst3"><li>Producten</li></div>
        <div class="menutekst1"><li>Home</li></div>

    </ul>
</nav>

<p id="hometekst">

    <strong>Welkom bij VE-Screen</strong><br>
    Ve-stoffering is een betrouwbare partner, denkt met u mee<br>
    en weet wat kwaliteit is of het nu gaat om uw woning, schip<br>
    of kantoor.<br>
    Onze kracht is de ervaring en goede samenwerking met u<br>
    als klant, de interieurbouwers en andere aannemers zodat<br>
    alles perfect op elkaar afgestemd en opgeleverd wordt.<br>
    Desgewenst incl. stoffering van banken, het leveren van<br>
    matrassen en bedtextiel en natuurlijk het plaatsen van ons<br>
    eigen Ve-screen zonwering.
</p>

<img id="home3" src="Foto/home3.png" />
<img id="home2" src="Foto/home2.png" />
<img id="home1" src="Foto/home1.png" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there could be multiple reasons this is happening. You probably need to define your layout in terms of %'s not fixed pixel lengths. You can also detect the resolution of the screen (viewport) and adjust accordingly. Without seeing your code theres not much anyone can do here....

Comment: You can't just set element sizes based on what looks good in your current browser and screen. Have you tried looking at your site in a mobile platform? Probably looks "f*cked" there as well. It would be easier to give a sensible answer if you provided some code.

Comment: write your HTML and CSS code :)

Comment: I know this has nothing to do with your problem... Why are you using Images for text... Talk about bad design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you're using the width as a percentage, then positioning your buttons absolutely. This means that the 100% value will adapt to the screen size but not the buttons' positions as they will always be absolutely positioned using the same values for each screen.

One solution could be to use one precise width value, another solution would be not to absolutely position the buttons and instead use the `float`property for the buttons. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, it worked thanks! Only problem is that everything is reversed now. Like, the normal format of the navigation bar should be: Home - Producten - Wie doen wij - Contact. But now it's: Contact - Wat doen wij - Producten - Home. Any idea how I fix that?

Comment: A quick fix would be to reverse their order in the code, another approach would be to put them all in a given container that would float right for example, and then float your elements left.

Comment: You're welcome, could you mark the question as solved by hitting that check button? Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem again but now with the text! Tried everything but I can't figure out how to fix it. And also, I have three pictures at the bottom of the page and they won't stay at their place as well. Do you or anyone else know how to fix this?